# AngularJS centralized control management

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that grew up over the last months to a dozen of states with over hundred controls (input, combos, etc...).

A security-service gives me a few user-roles back (for instance a "read-only" role).

Now I'd like to know how you guys handle the management of the app's controls? I would like to to have a centralized logic/place where I could set the controls states (grey-out, disable or even hide).

I was thinking to have a own logic/schema of control IDs -> Assign each control a unique HTML ID. like "app.state.panel.control". Then based on that I could en-/di-sable a single, all or a part of the controls (for instance "state.panel.*" would address all controls of one panel).

What do you think? Any documentation discussing this topic? Any known existing Angular modules?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use ng-if with a role-based conditional?